# jQuery: select next div outside of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Ok, I feel like I"m missing something really simple but here goes:

This code works great, exactly the way I want it to. You click the link and the next div is revealed (There are about 10 of these on a page)

```
    $('a.addtask').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.field').slideToggle();
    return false;
    });

  <div class="field">
   Some content
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="addtask">Add a task</a>

  <div class="field" style="display:none;">
    some other content
  </div>
```

What I want to do however is change the HTML like so (link inside the div):

```
<div class="field">
   Some content
   <a href="#" class="addtask">Add a task</a>
  </div>


  <div class="field" style="display:none;">
    some other content
  </div>
```

^^Which doesn't work properly anymore.

What do I need to change in my jquery to make this work? I've been googling for a while now and a number of solutions in similar posts dont seem to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$(".addtask").parent().next(".field")` should work

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `$(".addtask").nextAll('.field').first()`

Comment: Please be aware when answering old questions with several answers, especially when one has been accepted.  You need to explain why your answer is better the other existing posts.

Answer (score 1):

I have done complete bins for above issue.

**DEMO:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9y

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field">
  Some content
  <a href="#" class="addtask">
    Add a task
  </a>
</div>
<div class="field" style="display:none;">
  some other content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.field{
  padding:7px;
  border:1px solid #4455f9;
  background:#74cca9;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('a.addtask').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.field').next('.field').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });

});
```